# How to escape colon `:` within a native SQL query in Hibernate?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have a native SQL query that looks like that :

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT
        XMLSERIALIZE
        (CONTENT
          XMLELEMENT
          (
            NAME \"ltc:DOAATLTC\",
            XMLATTRIBUTES
            (
              'http://www.edftrading.com/Trade/Common/DoaatLTC' AS \"xmlns:ltc\",
              'http://www.edftrading.com/Trade/Common/DoaatLTCHourlyNomination' AS \"xmlns:ltchnom\"
            ),
            XMLELEMENT ( ... ) FROM ...");
```

The thing is that Hibernate interprets `:DOAATLTC\",` , `:ltc\",` , `:ltchnom\",` as parameters and expects that we give values `query.setString("DOAATLTC\",", ...)` , `query.setString("ltc\",", ...)` , `query.setString("ltchnom\",", ...)`

But I do not want Hibernate to interpret like that, so I want to escape the colon `:`.

How to do that ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In Hibernate, escaping is done with prepending by `\`. But in Java, you also have to escape `\` by another `\`. So every `:` needs to be replaced by `\\:`. Finally, you get:

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT
    XMLSERIALIZE
    (CONTENT
      XMLELEMENT
      (
        NAME \"ltc\\:DOAATLTC\",
        XMLATTRIBUTES
        (
          'http://www.edftrading.com/Trade/Common/DoaatLTC' AS \"xmlns\\:ltc\",
          'http://www.edftrading.com/Trade/Common/DoaatLTCHourlyNomination' AS \"xmlns\\:ltchnom\"
        ),
        XMLELEMENT ( ... ) FROM ...");
```

Comment: Just tried it but it does not work. It says : `ERROR: ORA-00911: caractère non valide`

Comment: No, it's different. Before, it was `Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.QueryException: Not all named parameters have been set: [ltc", DOAATLTC", ltchnom"]`

Comment: Wait, after thinking a bit. You are certainly right and this error message `ERROR: ORA-00911: caractère non valide` must be a new error message as the precedent `Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.QueryException: Not all named parameters have been set: [ltc", DOAATLTC", ltchnom"]` has been solved by your solution.

Comment: Well, I fixed the second Error message that had anything to do with the problem of that question. So, I can guarantee that your solution works fine.

Comment: If you used a text block to write your query, this solution will not work since a \ that's not at the end of the line is not a valid escape character in text blocks. You's have to go with @rogerdpack's approach

Answer (score 7):

If your colon is a cast like `SELECT reltuples::BIGINT` then you can rewrite it as a `cast(reltuples as BIGINT)` to avoid the colons.

[ref](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-do-solve-the-postgresql-cast-operator-issue-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)