# Escape colon (':') in custom h2 Query

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, h2

So I am trying to write a custom query for h2 using its JSON_OBJECT function. JSON_OBJECT uses a format of `JSON_OBJECT(key:value)` so as a simple example in my Spring repository I am writing a query like `@Query(value = "SELECT JSON_OBJECT('id':1)", nativeQuery = true)`

When executing that same query in the h2-console it operates as expected but in Spring the colon(':') is treated as a special character for variable insertion so when testing it, it tries to map the following value as a variable which of course throws an error.

I've tried escaping the colon with `\\` and `\\\\`  and putting a space between the colon and the value but doesnt seem to help.

Any ideas on how to either escape the char or make spring think the colon is an acceptable character?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to escape colon \`:\` within a native SQL query in Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32076306/how-to-escape-colon-within-a-native-sql-query-in-hibernate)

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri Presumably not, because all that answer says is to use two backslashes which the OP already tried.

Comment: Double chech \\ escaping as it shold do the tricke

Comment: @Michael yes, comment author also states that it didn't work initially, but then they elaborate (in the comments), and finally they have the solution. Maybe OP can, at least, double check the provided snippet, with his code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can simply use the alternative syntax `JSON_OBJECT(KEY 'id' VALUE 1)`, there is no need to use escaped `\\:`, escape sequences make your query less readable.

Comment: Thank You! I figured there was probably another way, but everytime I searched it led me back to h2 docs which only showed the colon way

Comment: Both syntax constructions are documented: https://h2database.com/html/functions.html#json_object