# Working postgresql query to native hibernate query PSQLException syntax error

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I have the below postgresql query which works fine if used directly on the db:

```
select memory_inmb from app where dt=(select dt from app where org='AAAA' 

AND to_timestamp(dt/1000) >= date_trunc('month', '2021-07-01 06:07:07+00'::timestamp) 

AND to_timestamp(dt/1000) < date_trunc('month', '2021-08-01 06:07:07+00'::timestamp) 

limit 1) AND org='AAAA';
```

In my repository I wrote it as a native query like this:

```
@Query(value="select a.memory_inmb from app a where a.dt=(select a.dt from app a where a.org='AAAA' AND to_timestamp(a.dt/1000) >= date_trunc('month', '2021-07-01 06:07:07+00'::timestamp) AND to_timestamp(a.dt/1000) < date_trunc('month', '2021-08-01 06:07:07+00'::timestamp) limit 1) AND a.org='AAAA'", nativeQuery = true)
    
List<BigInteger> findMemory();
```

In my implementation class for now I just call `return this.appRepository.findMemory();`

This gives me the following syntax exception:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near ":"
  Position: 148
```

How come I can run the query directly on the db just fine, but using it as native query doesn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Colons need to be escaped, so `::` for JPA should become `\\:\\:`, as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32076541
(for JPA `:` indicates a named parameter)

In your case you may also replace the `::` cast by the `CAST (myData as timestamp)` syntax.

Comment: That did it, thanks a lot!