# Error with query in java that works under database directly

Tags: java, postgresql, nativequery

I have this POSTGRESQL query:

```
select distinct on (a.id) a.id, p.app
from application a inner join package p on a.app_id = p.app_id 
where p.status = 'r'
ORDER BY a.app_id, (regexp_matches(p.app_ver, '^(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)'))[1]::integer DESC,
          (regexp_matches(p.app_ver, '^(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)'))[2]::integer DESC,
          (regexp_matches(p.app_ver, '^(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)'))[3]::integer DESC
```

And this seems to work perfectly when I run in on the database directly. (Its returning all the packages with latest version)
But when I call this query from Java method I get the error And I see from logs that the error is : ***ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":" at character 593***
and it seems that this created query translates to

```
select distinct on (a.id) a.id, p.app
from application a inner join package p on a.app_id = p.app_id 
where p.status = 'r'
ORDER BY a.app_id, (regexp_matches(p.app_ver, '^(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)'))[1]:integer DESC,
          (regexp_matches(p.app_ver, '^(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)'))[2]:integer DESC,
          (regexp_matches(p.app_ver, '^(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)'))[3]:integer DESC
```

Like its missing one : .
The way I pass this query is:

```
String query = BASE_QUERY +
                "WHERE  p.status = :status ORDER BY a.app_id, (regexp_matches(p.app_ver, '^(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)'))[1]::integer DESC,\n" +
                "          (regexp_matches(p.app_ver, '^(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)'))[2]::integer DESC,\n" +
                "          (regexp_matches(p.app_ver, '^(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)'))[3]::integer DESC";
        List<Application> fullList = entityManager.createNativeQuery(appListQuery, "Application")
            .setParameter("status", PACKAGE_READY.getValue())
            .getResultList();
```

Also another ERROR from log is the : ***Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet***

Data from table colum app_ver is like:

```
21.9.0-3-dev
21.9.0-3-dev-03
21.9.0-6
3.0.13-1
3.0.13-1
3.0.13-1
3.0.13-1
21.9.0-2
21.9.0-2
3.0.13-1
21.9.0-2
21.9.0-2
21.9.0-144
3.0.13-1
21.9.0-2
21.9.0-4-devtest
21.9.0-170
21.9.0-170
21.9.0-170
21.9.0-170
21.9.0-170
21.9.0-170
21.9.0-170
21.9.0-170
```

What could be wrong with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of the details but it seems that hibernate does some processing of your query, probably the `:` is some special char for it

did you tried to escape it? [How to escape colon `:` within a native SQL query in Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32076306/how-to-escape-colon-within-a-native-sql-query-in-hibernate)

or put 4 of them given that when you use two in the query being run they become just 1?

Comment: :::: solved this issue.